# How to make enum types in PL/SQL?

Tags: plsql

For example I want to make my own Boolean type and call it Bool. How do I do that?

Or a type for traffic lights, i.e. that has only Red, Yellow, Green in it (and null of course).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest think I could think of is:

```
create or replace type lights as object
(
  red varchar2(8),
  yellow varchar2(8),
  green varchar2(8),
constructor function lights return self as result
)
```

and the body:

```
create or replace type body lights is
constructor function lights return self as result is
begin
  self.red = 'red';
  self.yellow = 'yellow';
  self.green = 'green';
  return;
end;
end;
```

Then in the code you can use it:

```
declare
l lights := new lights;
begin
   dbms_output.put_line(l.red);
end;
```

Answer (score 11):

I don't think that solution, provided by *A.B.Cade* is totally correct. Let's assume procedure like this:

`procedure TestEnum(enum_in lights);`

What is the value of `enum_in`? red? yellow? green?

I propose another solution. Here is package example

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg_test_enum IS

  SUBTYPE TLight IS BINARY_INTEGER RANGE 0..2;
  Red CONSTANT TLight := 0;
  Yellow CONSTANT TLight := 1;
  Green CONSTANT TLight := 2;

  --get sting name for my "enum" type
  FUNCTION GetLightValueName(enum_in TLight) RETURN VARCHAR2;

  PROCEDURE EnumTest(enum_in TLight);

END pkg_test_enum;


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg_test_enum IS 
  FUNCTION GetLightValueName(enum_in TLight) 
  RETURN VARCHAR2
  IS
    ResultValue VARCHAR2(6);
  BEGIN
    CASE enum_in 
      WHEN Red THEN ResultValue := 'Red';
      WHEN Green THEN ResultValue := 'Green';
      WHEN Yellow THEN ResultValue := 'Yellow';
      ELSE ResultValue := '';
    END CASE;
    RETURN ResultValue;
  END GetLightValueName;


  PROCEDURE EnumTest(enum_in TLight)
  IS
  BEGIN
    --do stuff
    NULL;
  END EnumTest;
END pkg_test_enum;
```

I can now use `TLight` in different packages. I can now test `enum_in` against predefined values or null.

Here is usage example

```
begin
  pkg_test_enum.EnumTest(pkg_test_enum.Red);
end;
```

Besides, you can make this type not nullable.

`SUBTYPE TLight IS BINARY_INTEGER RANGE 0..2 NOT NULL;`

Answer (score 5):

[This blog describes a way to do it using constant values](http://www.petefinnigan.com/weblog/archives/00001246.htm)

In addition to the constants, the blog defines a subtype for valid colors.

```
SQL> declare
  2  RED constant number(1):=1;
  3  GREEN constant number(1):=2;
  4  BLUE constant number(1):=3;
  5  YELLOW constant number(1):=4;
  6  --
  7  VIOLET constant number(1):=7;
  8  --
  9  subtype colors is binary_integer range 1..4;
 10  --
 11  pv_var colors;
 12  --
 13  function test_a (pv_var1 in colors) return colors
 14  is
 15  begin
 16     if(pv_var1 = YELLOW) then
 17             return(BLUE);
 18     else
 19             return(RED);
 20     end if;
 21  end;
 22  --
```

Comment: It doesn't - I found a blog and didn't read it as carefully as I should have. Follow the link in my revised answer and you will find how to do it.

Comment: Another approach by [using a set](http://thinkoracle.blogspot.com/2005/05/enum-in-oracle.html). SQLPlus-friendly [source code](https://bitbucket.org/janihur/orasql-ex/src/tip/enum.sql) is also available for both examples.

Comment: Thanks Zulu. I've added the crucial parts directly in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have previously used the same approach as @mydogtom and @klas-lindbäck.  I found this when I was trying to refresh my memory.  However, the object approach suggested by @a-b-cade got me thinking.  I agree with the problems described by @mydogtom (what is the value?) but it got me thinking is using an object was possible.

What I came up with was an approach that used an object with a single member property for the value of the enum and static functions for each possible value.  I couldn't see how to combine with a subtype to get a real restriction on the value field, not to formally make it not-null.  However, we can validate it in the constructor.  The functional downside, compared to a "proper" enum (e.g. in Java) is that we can't stop someone directly updating the `val` property to an invalid value.  However, as long as people use the constructor and the set_value function, it's safe.  I'm not sure the overhead (both run-time in terms of creating an object and in terms of maintaining the objects, etc.) is worth it, so I'll probably keep using the approach described by @mydogtom but I'm not sure.

You could also have name as a property and set in in `set_value` (kind of like @a-b-cade's version) but that adds another property that could be updated directly and so another set of states where the val and name don't match, so I preferred the approach with name being a function.

An example usage of this could be (using my `demo_enum` type below):

```
procedure do_stuff(enum in demo_enum) is
begin
   if enum.eqals(demo_enum.foo()) then
      -- do something
   end if;
end do_stuff;
```

or

```
procedure do_stuff(enum1 in demo_enum, enum2 in demo_enum) is
begin
   if enum1.eqals(enum2) then
      -- do something
   end if;
end do_stuff;
```

What I did was define a base class, with as much as possible there: the actual `val` field, `equals` function for static values, `set_value` and `to_string` fucntions.  Also `name` function, but this just be overridden (couldn't see how to formally make a member function abstract, so the base version just throws an exception).  I'm using `name` also as the way to check the value is valid, in order to reduce the number of places I need to enumerate the possible values

```
create or replace type enum_base as object(
    -- member field to store actual value
    val integer,

    -- Essentially abstract name function
    -- Should be overridden to return name based on value
    -- Should throw exception for null or invalid values
    member function name return varchar2,

    --
    -- Used to update the value.  Called by constructor
    --
    member procedure set_value(pvalue in integer),
    
    --
    -- Checks the current value is valid
    -- Since we can't stop someone updating the val property directly, you can supply invalid values
    --
    member function isValid return boolean,
    
    --
    -- Checks for equality with integer value 
    -- E.g. with a static function for a possible value:   enum_var.equals( my_enum_type.someval() )
    --    
    member function equals(other in integer) return boolean,
        
    --
    -- For debugging, prints out name and value (to get just name, use name function)
    --      
    member function to_string return varchar2
    
    
) not instantiable not final;
/

create or replace type body enum_base is

    member function name return varchar2 is
    begin
        -- This function must be overriden in child enum classes.
        -- Can't figure out how to do an abstract function, so just throw an error
        raise invalid_number;
    end;
    
    member procedure set_value(pvalue in integer) is
        vName varchar2(3);
    begin
        self.val := pvalue;
        -- call name() in order to also validate that value is valid
        vName := self.name;                          
    end set_value;
    
            
    member function isValid return boolean is
        vName varchar2(3);
    begin
        begin
            -- call name() in order to also validate that value is valid
            vName := self.name;   
            return true; 
        exception
            when others then
                return false;
        end;            
    end isValid;
    
    
    member function equals(other in integer) return boolean is
    begin
        return self.val = other;
    end equals;
    
    member function to_string return varchar2 is
    begin 
        if self.val is null then
            return 'NULL';
        end if;

        return self.name || ' (' || self.val || ')';
    end to_string;
end;
/
```

In the actual enum class I have to define a constructor (which just calls `set_value`) and override the `name` function to return a name for each possible value.  I then define a static function for each possible value that returns the integer index of that value.  Finally I define an overload of `equals` that compares to another enum of the same type.  If you wanted to attach other properties to each value then you an do so by defining additional functions.

```
create or replace type demo_enum under enum_base (
            
    -- Note: the name of the parameter in the constructor MUST be the same as the name of the variable.  
    -- Otherwise a "PLS-00307: too many declarations" error will be thrown when trying to instanciate
    -- the object using this constructor         
    constructor function demo_enum(val in integer) return self as result,
    
    --
    -- Override name function from base to give name for each possible value and throw 
    -- exception for null/invalid values
    --
    overriding member function name return varchar2,
    
    --
    -- Check for equality with another enum object
    --  
    member function equals(other in demo_enum) return boolean,

    
    --
    -- Define a function for each possible value
    --
    static function foo return integer,
    static function bar return integer
        
) instantiable final;
/

create or replace type body demo_enum is
    
    constructor function demo_enum(val in integer) return self as result is        
    begin   
        self.set_value(val);        
        return;     
    end demo_enum;
    
    
    overriding member function name return varchar2 is
    begin
        if self.val is null then
            raise invalid_number;
        end if;
        
        case self.val
            when demo_enum.foo() then
                return 'FOO';
            when demo_enum.bar() then
                return 'BAR';
            else 
                raise case_not_found; 
        end case;
    end;    
        
    member function equals(other in demo_enum) return boolean is
    begin
        return self.val = other.val;
    end equals;
            
    static function foo return integer is
    begin 
        return 0;
    end foo;
    
    static function bar return integer is
    begin 
        return 1;
    end bar;    

end;
/
```

This can be tested.  I defined two sets of tests.  one was a manual set of tests for this particular enum, also to illustrate usage:

```
--
-- Manual tests of the various functions in the enum
--
declare
    foo demo_enum := demo_enum(demo_enum.foo());
    alsoFoo demo_enum := demo_enum(demo_enum.foo());
    bar demo_enum := demo_enum(demo_enum.bar());
    
    vName varchar2(100);    
    
    procedure assertEquals(a in varchar2, b in varchar2) is
    begin
        if a <> b then
            raise invalid_number;
        end if;
    end assertEquals;
    
    procedure assertEquals(a in boolean, b in boolean) is
    begin
        if a <> b then
            raise invalid_number;
        end if;
    end assertEquals;
    
    procedure test(vName in varchar2, enum in demo_enum, expectFoo in boolean) is
    begin
        dbms_output.put_line('Begin Test of ' || vName);
        if enum.equals(demo_enum.foo()) then
            dbms_output.put_line(vName || ' is foo');
            assertEquals(expectFoo, true);
        else
            dbms_output.put_line(vName || ' is not foo');
            assertEquals(expectFoo, false);
        end if;
        
        if enum.equals(demo_enum.bar()) then
            dbms_output.put_line(vName || ' is bar');
            assertEquals(expectFoo, false);
        else
            dbms_output.put_line(vName || ' is not bar');
            assertEquals(expectFoo, true);
        end if;
                
        if enum.equals(foo) then
            dbms_output.put_line(vName || '.equals(vFoo)');
            assertEquals(expectFoo, true);
        else
            assertEquals(expectFoo, false);
        end if;
        
        if expectFoo then
            assertEquals(enum.name, 'FOO');
        else
            assertEquals(enum.name, 'BAR');
        end if;
        
        assertEquals(enum.isValid, true);
        
        case enum.val
            when demo_enum.foo() then
                dbms_output.put_line(vName || ' matches case foo');
            when demo_enum.bar() then
                dbms_output.put_line(vName || ' matches case bar');
            else
                dbms_output.put_line(vName || ' matches no case!!!');
        end case;
        
        dbms_output.put_line(vName || ': ' || enum.to_string());
        dbms_output.put_line('--------------------------------------------------');
        dbms_output.put_line('');
    end test;
begin    
    test('foo', foo, true);
    test('bar', bar, false);
    test('alsoFoo', alsoFoo, true);
        
    
    foo.val := -1;
    assertEquals(foo.isValid, false);    
    begin
        vName := foo.name;    
    exception
        when case_not_found then
            dbms_output.put_line('Correct exception for fetching name when invalid value: ' || sqlerrm);
    end;
    
    foo.val := null;
    assertEquals(foo.isValid, false);    
    begin
        vName := foo.name;    
    exception
        when invalid_number then
            dbms_output.put_line('Correct exception for fetching name when null value: ' || sqlerrm);
    end;
end;
```

The other was slightly more automated, and could be used for any enum that inherits `enum_base` (as long as it doesn't add other functions - couldn't see a way to find only static functions, if anyone knows let me know).  This checks that you haven't defined the same integer value to multiple possible value static functions by mistake:

```
--
-- generated test that no two values are equal 
--
declare
    vSql varchar2(4000) := '';
    
    typename constant varchar2(20) := 'demo_enum';
    
    cursor posvals is   
        select procedure_name
        from user_procedures
        where object_name = upper(typename)
          and procedure_name not in (upper(typename), 'EQUALS', 'NAME');

    cursor posvals2 is   
        select procedure_name
        from user_procedures
        where object_name = upper(typename)
          and procedure_name not in (upper(typename), 'EQUALS', 'NAME');


    procedure addline(line in varchar2) is
    begin
        vSql := vSql || line || chr(10);
    end;
begin
    addline('declare');
    addline('   enum ' || typename || ';');
    addline('begin');
        
    for posval in posvals loop    
        addline('   enum := ' || typename || '(' || typename || '.' || posval.procedure_name || '());');    
        for otherval in posvals2 loop
            addline('   if enum.equals(' || typename || '.' || otherval.procedure_name || '()) then');
            if otherval.procedure_name = posval.procedure_name then                 
                addline('      dbms_output.put_line(''' || otherval.procedure_name || ' = ' || posval.procedure_name || ''');');
            else
                addline('      raise_application_error(-20000, ''' || otherval.procedure_name || ' = ' || posval.procedure_name || ''');');
            end if;
            addline('   else');
            if otherval.procedure_name = posval.procedure_name then                 
                addline('      raise_application_error(-20000, ''' || otherval.procedure_name || ' != ' || posval.procedure_name || ''');');
            else
                addline('      dbms_output.put_line(''' || otherval.procedure_name || ' != ' || posval.procedure_name || ''');');
            end if;
            addline('   end if;');
        end loop;        
        addline('');
    end loop;
    addline('end;');
    
    execute immediate vSql;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

For example enum whith "yes" and "no" values.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_yes_no_enum AS OBJECT
( yes_no NUMBER
, CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION t_yes_no_enum
  ( yes_no NUMBER
  )
  RETURN SELF AS RESULT
, STATIC FUNCTION yes
  RETURN t_yes_no_enum
, STATIC FUNCTION no
  RETURN t_yes_no_enum
, MAP MEMBER FUNCTION yes_no_map
  RETURN NUMBER
) ;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE TYPE BODY t_yes_no_enum
AS

CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION t_yes_no_enum
( yes_no NUMBER
)
RETURN SELF AS RESULT
IS
BEGIN
  self.yes_no := yes_no ;

  IF  utl_call_stack.dynamic_depth > 1
  AND utl_call_stack.unit_type(2) = 'TYPE BODY'
  AND utl_call_stack.concatenate_subprogram(utl_call_stack.subprogram(2)) LIKE 'T_YES_NO_ENUM.%'
  AND utl_call_stack.owner ( 2 ) = utl_call_stack.owner ( 1 )
  THEN
    NULL ;
  ELSE
    raise_application_error ( -20184 , 'Constructor calling prohibited. For object type creation use it''s static factory methods.' ) ;
  END IF ;

  RETURN ;
END ;

STATIC FUNCTION yes
RETURN t_yes_no_enum
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN NEW t_yes_no_enum ( 1 ) ;
END ;

STATIC FUNCTION no
RETURN t_yes_no_enum
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN NEW t_yes_no_enum ( 2 ) ;
END ;

MAP MEMBER FUNCTION yes_no_map
RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
  IF coalesce ( self.yes_no , -999 ) NOT IN ( 1 , 2 ) THEN
    raise_application_error ( -20185 , 'Changing object type attribute value prohibited.' ) ;
  END IF ;
  RETURN self.yes_no ;
END ;

END ;
```